# React Icon component with SVG's

Tags: reactjs, svg, icons

I have a folder name `icons` that contains a lot of SVG files. Every file is an independent icon that looks like that:

**icons/heart.svg** (I want to avoid converting it to JS)

```
<svg height="24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M22.178 13.583l-9.131 8.992a1.502 1.502 0 0 1-2.094 0l-9.131-8.992a6.192 6.192 0 0 1 0-8.773c2.439-2.413 6.395-2.413 8.834 0L12 6.154l1.344-1.344c2.439-2.413 6.395-2.413 8.834 0a6.192 6.192 0 0 1 0 8.773"/></svg>
```

I want to create a component that will load an svg based on its name.

**components/Icon.js**

```
export const Icon = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <svg height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img">
      <path d={name} />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

**Example usage I look for: (App.js)**

```
<Icon name="heart" />  // should load heart.svg
<Icon name="star" /> // should load star.svg
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a file which exports all your svg file and give name to each one of them.

```
import heart from './icons/heart.svg'

export { heart };
```

Then you can import your icon anywhere you want according to the name;

```
import { heart } from './<path_of_above_file>'
```

if you want to create an Icon component then create a component and render the icon in there.

```
export const Icon = ({ icon, ...props }) => {
  return (
   <div {...props}>
     {icon}
   </div>
  );
};
```

Then use it anywhere you like.

```
import { heart } from './path_of_above_file';
<Icon icon={heart} />
```

Another solution is passing path as a prop;

```
export const Icon = ({ path, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <svg {...props} viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img">
      <path d={path} />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

And use the icon passing the path as a prop.

```
<Icon path='M22.178 13.583l-9.131 8.992a1.502 1.502 0 0 1-2.094 0l-9.131-8.992a6.192 6.192 0 0 1 0-8.773c2.439-2.413 6.395-2.413 8.834 0L12 6.154l1.344-1.344c2.439-2.413 6.395-2.413 8.834 0a6.192 6.192 0 0 1 0 8.773' height="24" width="24" />
```

Comment: That is a fantastic direction, thank you! One last thing to close this - can I wrap `{icon}` with my own `<svg>` tag? so I can use dynamic classnames/sizes/etc

Comment: You can have your classnames and sized on the div which wraps the icon.

Comment: Yes, But I can't change `viewBox` or other attributes

Comment: In that case you can follow the instruction given here https://css-tricks.com/creating-svg-icon-system-react/

Comment: I kind of got lost there. It doesn't look so relevant. Once again, I want to use the system you proposed but I also want to have control on the `<svg>` tag, and not "throw" it entirely (so basically, I want to strip the `<svg>` tag

Comment: Its because you are trying to create svg file inside `<path d={name} />`. If you already have a svg file, you shouldn't create svg inside svg.

Comment: Can you take a look on Pinterest design system? They are doing exactly what I want to do. https://github.com/pinterest/gestalt/blob/c3e7895edaf3bd2aed73018860cf9daa6dbeba6c/packages/gestalt/src/Icon.js#L90

Comment: Its because they are just passing path as a prop but in your case you have the svg file.

Comment: It looks like they use the whole svg, check the icons file here: https://github.com/pinterest/gestalt/blob/c3e7895edaf3bd2aed73018860cf9daa6dbeba6c/packages/gestalt/src/icons/index.js

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to convert SVG icon files to JS; it has already been done.

```html
<svg-icon is=heart></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=heart fill="green" scale=".8"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=heart fill="green" scale=".8" rotate="45"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=smile></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=smile fill="gold" stroke="green" width="5"></svg-icon>
```

[image]

But.. it is a **modern W3C standard Web Component** `<svg-icon is="heart"></svg-icon>`

Alas [React doesn't comply with modern Web Standards](https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/libraries/react/results/results.html) so **you** have to make it work in React.

For the IconMeister Web Component: https://iconmeister.github.io/
I converted **7300+** icons from major iconsets to JSON notation:

With this JSON (note you can specifiy different viewBoxes from different Icon Sets)

```
{ 
"heart" : "box:36;fill:red;path:M33 8c-1-3-5-5-10-4A10 10 0 0018 8A10 10 0 0013 4C8 3 
           4 5 3 8c-2 4-1 8 2 13c3 4 7 7 12 12a1 1 0 001 0c5-5 9-8 12-12c4-5 4-9 3-13z",
"smile": "box:128;fill:#000;path:M62 2C28 2 0 30 0 64s28 62 62 62s62-28 62-62S97 2 62 2z
          m0 112c-28 0-50-23-50-50S35 14 62 14s50 23 50 50s-23 50-50 50zm30-37c-3-3-7-2-9
          1c-6 7-13 10-21 10s-16-4-21-10c-3-3-6-3-9-1c-3 3-3 6-1 9c8 9 19 15 31 15s23-6 
          31-15c3-3 2-7-1-9zM42 60c5 0 8-4 8-8s-4-8-8-8s-8 4-8 8s4 8 8 8zm40-15c-7 0-14 
          5-15 11c-1 3 3 5 5 3l3-3c4-4 12-4 16 0l3 3c3 2 6 0 5-3c-1-7-9-11-15-11z"
}
```

The **796 Bytes!** `<svg-icon>` Web Component uses **standard HTML** to create **and** control SVG:

```html
<svg-icon is=heart></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=heart fill="green" scale=".8"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=heart fill="green" scale=".8" rotate="45"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=smile></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=smile fill="gold" stroke="green" width="5"></svg-icon>
```

and style:

```
<style>
  svg-icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width:120px;
    background:lightgreen;
  }
</style>
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

#### Full Web Component code:

No Libraries, No Frameworks, No external SVG files, No dependencies

Documentation and source at: https://iconmeister.github.io/

```html
<style>
  svg-icon {
    display:inline-block;
    width:120px;
    background:lightgreen;
  }
</style>

<svg-icon is=heart></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=heart fill="green" scale=".8"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=heart fill="green" scale=".8" rotate="45"></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=smile></svg-icon>
<svg-icon is=smile fill="gold" stroke="green" width="5"></svg-icon>

<script>
((t,e={path:(t,e="")=>`<path d='${t}' ${e}/>`},i={stroke:"#000",rect:"<rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='{tile}' {border}/>",fill:"none",tile:"none",img:1,width:1,scale:1,opacity:1,is:"",border:"",filter:"",top:"",v1:"",v2:"",v3:"",box:9,rotate:0,xy:0,w:0,h:0,api:[t,e]})=>{customElements.define("svg-icon",class extends HTMLElement{static get observedAttributes(){return Object.keys(i)}attributeChangedCallback(){this.svg()}svg(s=this,r=s.A||Object.keys(s.A={...i}).map((t=>Object.defineProperty(s,t,{set:e=>s.setAttribute(t,e),get:()=>s.getAttribute(t)||getComputedStyle(s).getPropertyValue("--svg-icon-"+t).replace(/"/g,"").trim()||s.A[t]},e[t]=e=>(s.A[t]=e,"")))),l,a=(t[s.is]||"").split`;`.map((t=>([r,l]=t.trim().split`:`,e[r]?e[r].apply(s,l.split`,`):t))).join``,o=s.box/2,c=`<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 ${s.w||s.box} ${s.h||s.box}' style='vertical-align:top'>${s.rect}<g stroke-width='{width}' stroke='{stroke}' fill='{fill}' opacity='{opacity}' filter='{filter}' transform='translate({xy}) matrix({scale} 0 0 {scale} ${o-o*s.scale} ${o-o*s.scale}) rotate({rotate} ${o} ${o})'>${a}</g>${s.top}</svg>`.replace(/{\s?([^{}\s]*)\s?}/g,((t,e)=>s[e]))){return s.innerHTML=1==s.img?`<img style='vertical-align:top' src="data:image/svg+xml,${c.replace(/#/g,"%23")}">`:c}})})(
{"heart":"box:36;fill:red;path:M33 8c-1-3-5-5-10-4A10 10 0 0018 8A10 10 0 0013 4C8 3 4 5 3 8c-2 4-1 8 2 13c3 4 7 7 12 12a1 1 0 001 0c5-5 9-8 12-12c4-5 4-9 3-13z",
"smile":"box:128;fill:#000;path:M62 2C28 2 0 30 0 64s28 62 62 62s62-28 62-62S97 2 62 2zm0 112c-28 0-50-23-50-50S35 14 62 14s50 23 50 50s-23 50-50 50zm30-37c-3-3-7-2-9 1c-6 7-13 10-21 10s-16-4-21-10c-3-3-6-3-9-1c-3 3-3 6-1 9c8 9 19 15 31 15s23-6 31-15c3-3 2-7-1-9zM42 60c5 0 8-4 8-8s-4-8-8-8s-8 4-8 8s4 8 8 8zm40-15c-7 0-14 5-15 11c-1 3 3 5 5 3l3-3c4-4 12-4 16 0l3 3c3 2 6 0 5-3c-1-7-9-11-15-11z"});
</script>
```

**PS.** The source is UNlicensed, I would love to see a React version in 796 Bytes (GZipped)

Answer (score 0):

You can have an object to map `path` name to its value:

```
const PATHS = {
  star: "M22.178 ...",
  heart: "A22.153 ...",
};

export const Icon = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <svg height="24" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img">
      <path d={PATHS[name]} />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you  - But that's not what I'm trying to do. I don't want to "move" my SVG's  content to a JS file. I want something like this (I just couldn't figure out the entire build, so I cant recreate it) https://github.com/pinterest/gestalt/blob/master/packages/gestalt/src/Icon.js